# undefined response with fetchHook

Tags: reactjs, undefined, react-hooks

I'm trying to do some basic fetching with hooks but I keep getting undefined as response.

//Hook

```
export  const useFetch = (url, initialValue) => {
const [Data, setData] = useState(initialValue);
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const result = await axios(url);
        setData(result);     
    };
    fetchData();    
}, []);
console.log(Data,'data') // undefined
return { Data, setData }
```

}

// component

```
  export default function BeerTable() {
  const classes = useStyles();
    const  data =   useFetch(
    "https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers/"
    );
    const { Beers, setBeers }= useState(data)
    console.log(Beers, 'beers')//undefined
    return (
     //some table
  )
}
```

the response I get when calling the endpoint on browser :

```
 [
  {
    "id": 192,
    "name": "Punk IPA 2007 - 2010",
    "tagline": "Post Modern Classic. Spiky. Tropical. Hoppy.",
    "first_brewed": "04/2007",
    "abv": 6.0,
    "ibu": 60.0,
    "target_fg": 1010.0,
    "target_og": 1056.0,
    "ebc": 17.0,
    "srm": 8.5,
    "ph": 4.4,
    "attenuation_level": 82.14,
    "volume": {
      "value": 20,
      "unit": "liters"
    },
  }
  .....]
```

what is wrong ???

Answer (score 1):

`fetchData` is updating `Data` in an async response. But it is returning `Data` before it has completed the fetch.

Meanwhile, in your component, you are assigning `data` only one time. It will go through the `useFetch` logic and grab what it returns instantly, which is `undefined.`

In order to get the changes from `useFetch`, you'll need to have a `useEffect` in your component that is watching for when `Data` changes.

```
// component
export default function BeerTable() {
  const [Beers, setBeers] = useState();
  const data = useFetch("htttps://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers/");    

  useEffect(() => {
    setBeers(data.Data);    
    console.log('beers got updated: ' + Beers');
  }, [data.Data]);
}
```

Comment: useFetch("htttps://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers/") returns undefined, the problem is coming from  the hook :/

Answer (score 0):

You're using object destructuring with an array, so no data is getting returned.

I'm not sure what youre trying to do with the data, but you may want to loop through it like this:

```js
const beerArray = useState(data)

for (var i=0; i<beerArray.length, i++){
  // Do stuff with each beer object here
}
```